# Display BootSideMenu in Frames

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

We have a Web Application where we are using 3-frames to display

- Header (Horizontal),
- Menu bar (Vertical right side) and
- Main content.

Here I would like to replace the Navigation with the bootstrap plugin `BootSideMenu` without disturbing the `Header` and `Main` frames. I tried many ways, but none of them did work out.

Could someone please help me by providing some guidelines?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask